# With boost::python return a list of exposed class objects, that are noncopyable

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have a BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE in which I have a function that I want to return a list of objects that I have exposed.

```
namespace bp = boost::python;

class MyClass {
public:
   int foo() {return 42;}
};

bp::list my_fun() {
   bp::list l;
   l.append(MyClass());
   l.append(MyClass());
   return l;
}


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_module) {
  bp::class_<MyClass,boost::noncopyable>("MyClass")
     .def("foo",&MyClass::foo);

  bp::def("my_fun",my_fun);
}
```

I get expection "No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type",

Comment: That won't even compile due to `MyClass::foo()` being private. Other than that, it works -- calling `my_fun()[0].foo()` returns 42.

Comment: @DanMasek Yes you are right, thank you for taking the time. The error was noncopyable keyword, that I didn't think to put into this simplified example.

Comment: You would need to add a reference wrapper or a pointer to your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caused by

boost::noncopyable

keyword.